# Is Proxy or state design pattern or perhaps iterator pattern more suitable in this case?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-pattern

In my application, all operations that are done are on the currently selected object which makes me think state design pattern is best fit. However all objects that are selected one by one are essentially the same so there is really no difference in each state except the item is just a different one.

My situation is a lot like directory structure. I have a collection of folders where each folder may have a different files but it is still a folder. Whatever folder is selected, user can only see contents of that folder or add files. My program also iterators through all folders (assume one level) and shows content of all files under the folder.

I am confused, how should I maintain the current state (=currently selected folder) in my application?

**Add-on**

What is also confusing me is the next state logic which I am not sure where it belongs. Please assume I am working with special folders `My Documents`, `My Pictures` and `My Music`. The transition logic  (for simplicity) is if user adds 10 files to any of these folders or the total size of each folder exceeds 10 MB, it should transition to the next folder. Furthermore application should first show `My Documents`, than transition into `My Pictures` and than transition into `My Music`. This is why I was thinking it as a state as well due to each folder need to know which folder it will need to transition.

Comment: Sure sounds to me as if `iterator` is the more suitable abstraction here.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I have added more information, do you think `iterator` is still more suitable pattern? thanks

Comment: May be open to more question, but not really a lot. An iterator normally represents some state (the current position) along with something that determines a "next position", as well as the ability to determine when iteration should cease. I don't see anything here that departs from that basic pattern of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can use combination of state and iterator pattern. If the states of the object are simple, you can implement state pattern just by using some enums representing folder state like OPEN or CLOSED. Iterator helps you maintain & access folder objects in general way.

Comment: It does seem like an `iterator` alone will not do the job because it can't differentiate one object from any other so I will have to create state but how can use state with iterator?